# How to package a Python project with DLL dependencies

Tags: python, python-packaging

My project structure:

```
├───bin
│   ├───Win32
│   │   └───Release
│   │       └───MyDLL.dll
│   └───x64
│       └───Release
│           └───MyDLL.dll
├───cpp
└───python
    ├───package
    └───setup.cfg (and others)
```

My Python `package` uses a C dependency, which gets loaded when I create an from my `package`. The code for it is in `cpp` directory. When I compile, the DLLs get placed in the `bin` folder. I have searched quite a lot, but there is little to no information about how I can package this type of project. The DLLs are no special Python DLLs, just normal DLLs with a few exported functions.